# How to share an existing facebook post to user timeline from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, share, facebook-ios-sdk

Our app shows some Facebook posts from artists that our users follows.
We want to enable our users to share posts they like back to their timeline (like the share button you see under each post in the Facebook Feed).

We tried to do this using the Facebook web dialogs, but we keep running into errors.
For example:
When trying to share a post of type photo: If we set a parameter "picture" with the picture url, we get an error that the feed dialog should not use a picture coming form the FBCDN.

We can share the photo as a link, but than the photo itself doesn't appear on the user timeline.

Is there a way to mimic the functionality of the built in share button?

Comment: I hade nothing but bugs when using the fb feed dialogue and ended up using the graph api directly to do wall posts. You might look in to that if you are still having issues.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the *"feed dialog should not use a picture coming form the FBCDN"*-problem: You might want to fetch the image url (use `https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID` to get the post object containing the url) and forward the image data via your own server. There are ways to hide the original url from the client (read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4031896/601466)) if Facebook still complains.